# Is it possible to remove a row from an RDD that has an empty string in the row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How would you remove a row from a scala RDD that has an empty string in it?

Comment: what's wrong with filter?

Comment: how abt using `filter`

Comment: This does not work for me

.filter(x => if( x._1.length >  0) x)

Comment: is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Yes, your syntax is wrong. You have an if clause without an else part. This always yields Unit and so will not work. See answer by @AssafMendelson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have an RDD called myRDD and it has a type of tuple with the first element being the string (building this by your comments).

You could do:

```
val newRDD = myRDD.filter(x => (x._1 != null) && (x._1.length > 0))
```

filter receives a function from the element to boolean. It is important generally also make sure it is not null before testing the length.

Comment: Don't you mean && instead of || ?

Comment: Correct. Fixed now.